# Is there a way to disable OCR mode in Tika without uninstalling tesseract

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, apache-tika

I am using tika-app jar for my project and is there a way to disable tesseract OCR in tika. There are two things which has to be kept as such:

1.tesseract cannot be uninstalled

2.tika.xml can't be edited, as tika-app.jar is used off the shelf

Is there a way to set the configuration in the **java** code by setting the context or parser property to disable OCR?

I tried the below code but still OCR extracts the text from image files while parsing.

````
            PDFParserConfig pdfConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
            pdfConfig.setOcrStrategy(OCR_STRATEGY.NO_OCR);
            context.set(PDFParserConfig.class, pdfConfig);```
````

Comment: The Tika App will happily accept a Tika Config xml file passed as a command line argument, why not do that?

Comment: Tika app is used as an external library file and it is configured that way. Is it possible to set it through java code?

Comment: Sure! Just create a `TikaConfig` object with your own settings, then pass that to the Tika code you're using

Comment: @Gagravarr I don't see any options related to ocr on `TikaConfig`, how would that be done?

Comment: @Adam see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tika/tikaocr#TikaOCR-OverridingDefaultConfiguration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <parsers>
        <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser">
       <parser-exclude class="org.apache.tika.parser.ocr.TesseractOCRParser"/>
        </parser>
    </parsers>
</properties>
```

Comment: The OP asked to set the configuration in the java code

Comment: You can make Tika to find it by setting environment property tika.config to the name of the config file, if it's not in one of the locations where Tika is looking for it, is seems full path should help. 

This way you do not even have to change your code.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do this with java as its only difference with the default config would be OCR removed; I'm not certain if the XML config does the same:

```
TikaConfig defaultConfig = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
CompositeParser compositeParser = (CompositeParser) defaultConfig.getParser();
Map<MediaType, Parser> parsers = compositeParser.getParsers();
parsers.values().removeIf(parser -> parser instanceof TesseractOCRParser);
compositeParser.setParsers(parsers);
Tika TIKA = new Tika(defaultConfig);
```